# Hypersurface Area of a Parameterized Hypersurface

Tags: area, surfaces, spheres, surface-integrals

Say you have a real unit $(M+1)$-vector $r_M$ which parameterizes some part of the $M$-sphere and is a function of parameters $\theta_1$ through $\theta_M$. How do we find the $M$-dimensional ``surface area" $S_M$ of vector $r_M$? For $M=2$ I know we can use
\begin{equation}
S_2=\int\Big|\frac{\partial r_2}{\partial \theta_1}\times\frac{\partial r_2}{\partial \theta_2}\Big|dA
\end{equation}

But the cross product is only defined for $3$ (and $7$?) dimensions. What is the generalization I'm looking for here? My best guess is:
\begin{equation}
S_M=\int\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{M+1}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{M+1}\epsilon_{ij_1...j_m}\frac{\partial r_{j_1}}{\partial\theta_1}...\frac{\partial r_{j_M}}{\partial\theta_M}\right)^2}d\theta_1...d\theta_M
\end{equation}

where $\epsilon$ is the Levi-Civita tensor of rank $M+1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>The generalization of surfave integrals in higher dimensions is done using differential forms. The volume form on the euclidian sphere $\mathbb S^{N-1}\subseteq \mathbb R^{N}$ is
$\omega= \sum_{i=1}^N (-1)^{i-1}x_i \text{d}x_1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{\text{d}x_i}\wedge\dots\wedge \text{d}x_N$. More on that in a [question I asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3128164/relationship-between-n-1-forms-and-flux-of-a-vector-field-across-a-hypersu), but since I don't know your background I'm not going to assume that knowledge and take a different approach.</sup>

In 2-dim surfaces in $\mathbb R^3$, the vector $\frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta}\times\frac{\partial r_2}{\partial \theta_2}$ represented a normal to the surface whose length measures the area of a small parallelogram. Integrating all of them gives the total area. Well, the cross product could be generalized to any dimension. The 3-7 case you are talking about is when you want the operation to be binary! We usually define the cross product of $v_1,\dots,v_{N}\in\mathbb R^{N+1}$

$$\Pi(v_1,\dots,v_{N})=\det\begin{bmatrix}
e_1 & \dots & e_{N+1}\\ 
 \cdots& v_1 & \cdots\\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ 
\cdots & v_{N} & \cdots
\end{bmatrix}$$
With the regular abuse of notation of standard basis vectors in the first row. It's clear that the result is orthogonal to all $v_i$s since doing a dot product with any of it yields a determinant with twice the row $v_i$ which yields zero. Showing it's length rightfully represents volume depends on your definition of $N$ volume, but it's not hard to see it's linear and permutation invariant at least as it should. To calculate the length, we see the $i$th component is
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}
v_{1}^1& \cdots & v_{1}^{i-1} & v_{1}^{i+1}&\cdots& v_{1}^N\\ 
\vdots &  & \vdots&\vdots & &\vdots\\ 
v_{N}^1& \cdots & v_{N}^{i-1} & v_{N}^{i+1}&\cdots& v_{N}^N
\end{bmatrix}=\epsilon_{i,j_1,\dots,j_N} v_{1}^{j_1}\cdots v_{N}^{j_N}$$

With this in mind we can do the same proccess in 2 dimensions and get that for an $N$-dim surface $\Sigma$ parameterized with $r$ on domain $\Omega$
$$\text{vol}_N(\Sigma)=\int_\Omega  \left \| \Pi\left ( \frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta_1},\dots,\frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta_N} \right ) \right \|_2 \text{d}\theta$$
Which gives an expression I reckon is close to yours but not precise, the $j$s are in the $\theta$ indices.

Comment: I think I have a question. I get the definition of a cross-product. However, what is the double-vertical-line notation denoting? Further, what is the subscript of $2$ indicating? Do the lines denote normalization of the resultant vector $\Pi\left(...\right)$? Does the subscript indicate just a "normal" normalization thing; i.e. sum of squares and square-root the whole thing?

Comment: Oh sorry for the notation. This is just the regular norm! the same one you had after doing the cross product just in a higher dimension. The double bar is different notataion which prevents confusion with absolute value and the 2 is there because it is a specific case of a $p$ norm $(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ for $p=2$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to work it out yesterday. My result is a big, impermeable mess of sums, products and Levi-Civita tensors all integrated over many variables but it is technically done.